# SF Symbols for Mac Apps

Tags: xcode, macos, fonts, sf-symbols

I am making a Mac App and want to use the new SF Symbols.

The SF Symbols are built into iOS 13 but they aren’t for Mac Apps.  The best you can do is copy and paste the SF Symbol into a textfield.  But whoever uses your app will have to download the SF Symbols app in order to see them.

- Is it possible to force users to download the SF Symbols app?
- SF Symbol -> SVG -> PNG [not allowed]

  - This is for a project at my Work so we are looking for scaleable solutions.  We can't use paintcode, sketch, or adobe.
- Is it possible to create my own custom font and add the SFSymbols into that?
- Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You can download a lot of the SF symbol (and a bunch of other ones too) on [this website](https://hotpot.ai/free-icons?s=sfSymbols). I don't know how to do it for macOS but for iOS I use the "iOS" option to download 3 .png files (1x, 2x, 3x) that you can add to your assets as a single image set. I'm using them for navigation bar items and they also react to the "global tint" color. Unfortunately you can't set the exact weight and scale on the website, as described by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) but it's better than nothing.